# List all of the folder name from S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to list all of the folders from my S3 bucket. In my s3 bucket I have folders for example : SF_test_01, SF_test_02, SF_test_03 etc. I used

```
for my_bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.all():
         print(my_bucket_object)
```

but its returning all paths with folder and file names. Is there anyway how to do it? I want only folder names. I can add that I'm using AWS Lambda function and I have imported boto3

Comment: S3 technically doesn't have folders, its flat object storage. The prefixes just give the appearance of directories.

Comment: OK, thanks for the information. But how it should help me with my problem ? ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `boto3` s3 slient, you can get a list of folders:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

result = s3.list_objects(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Delimiter='/')
for prefix in result.get('CommonPrefixes', list()):
    print(prefix.get('Prefix', ''))
```

Comment: That's very nice code for avoiding errors where certain dictionary entries don't exist! I might adopt that style myself.

Comment: @wilkux This answer should've solved your query. If it did, please accept this answer to close this thread.